# vim, How do I get matching word in parenthesis from regex

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

with vim script,

Let me say that I want to find word "This" from the following expression

`match("testingThis", '\ving(.*)')`

I tried with some different options, `getmatches()`, `substitute()`, not luck yet :(

Is there a way get matches in vim like in ruby or php, i.e. `matches[1]`

--------------------------EDIT----------------------------

from `h function-list`, as `glts` mentioned, I found `matchlist()`
unlike `matchstr()`, which always returns full matches, like matches[0], it returns full array of matches.

```
echo matchstr("foo bar foo", '\vfoo (.*) foo')  " return foo bar foo
echo matchlist("foo bar foo", '\vfoo (.*) foo')  " returns ['foo bar foo', 'bar', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use `matchstr()` (which returns the match itself, not the start position), and let the match start after the *before*-assertion with `\zs`:

```
matchstr("testingThis", '\ving\zs(.*)')
```

In the general case, there's `matchlist()`, which returns a List of the entire match plus all captured groups. The result is in the first capture group, so the element at index 1:

```
matchlist("testingThis", '\ving(.*)')[1]
```